# How can I assign values for a map-type in an archetype test script?

Tags: smart-contracts, testing, types, archetype

I have the following typescript in my test script:

```
const tmdBytes = Bytes.hex_encode("ipfs://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
const tmdMap : Array<[ string, Bytes ]> = [" ", tmdBytes]
```

The second line is giving me the errors:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '[string, Bytes]'.
Type 'Bytes' is not assignable to type '[string, Bytes]'.
```

I have tried to copy [the example in the docs](https://archetype-lang.org/docs/tests/binding#map) which is:

```
const ledger : Array<[ Address, Int ]> = []
```

The errors of course go away if I remove the values from the array, copying the docs exactly, but then I don't know how to add the values to the Map/Array.

My goal is to pass this array as a parameter in a test script, eg:

```
    await fa2_contract.mint(
      ownerAddress
      tmdMap,      
      {})
```

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try with this:

```
const tmdMap : Array<[ string, Bytes ]> = [[" ", tmdBytes]]
```

In typescript, tuple and array have the same literal `[]`.
And here, it is a tuple into an array.

Answer (score 1):

The expected type reads "an array of pairs of string and bytes", and `[" ", tmdBytes]` is just a pair, hence I guess the following value should make ti:

```
const tmdMap : Array<[ string, Bytes ]> = [ [" ", tmdBytes] ]
```

As a side note, maps/assets are transpiled to arrays of *pairs* (asset) key and (asset) value, and the TS syntax for both arrays and tuples is `[ ]`. The reason for not transpiling to TS map objects is because the types of keys in TS maps does not deal easily with complex/composed keys.